# Which combinatorial problem is similar to this problem?

Tags: complexity-theory

I have $n$ clients and for each client I have different options to choose from, for example, $C= \{C_1,C_2 \}$. For each combination of $n$ options, there is a cost. I want to choose the best combination that minimizes the cost without calculating the cost for each option one by one and then choose the best one and I do not have any constraints. Which combinatorial problem is similar to this one?

For example, If I have $n=3$ and $C =\{1,2\}$, I have set of triples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ as $\mathcal{M}= \{(1,2,1),(1,2,2),(1,1,1),(1,1,2),(2,1,1),(2,1,2),(2,2,1),(2,2,2)\}$ and equation $cost=x_1+x_2+2x_3$ I want to find the triple that minimizes the cost without calculating one by one. The cost function can be any function not nessesary linear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cost function can be any function, then in general there is no algorithm whose performance is better trying all possibilities (in terms of worst-case performance).

This is indicating to you that if you want to do better, you will need to know something about the cost function and take advantage of some structure or properties it has.

Answer (score 3):

In a very literal sense, [D.W.'s answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/118848/8311) is correct. In the absence of any information about the cost function, there are no alternatives better than simply trying the cost function at each possible input.

However, in real-world applications, we usually know *something* about the cost function—and as soon as we have a little bit of structure, we can leverage that to create more efficient search strategies.

For example, if the cost function has a relatively simple closed form in terms of the inputs, you may be able to apply an optimizing SMT solver such as the widely-used [Z3 from Microsoft Research](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3) (interactive tutorial [here](https://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/guide)). These solvers use complex strategies to locate and exploit hidden structure in the input problem and find solutions more efficiently than brute-force search.